# PHP can't find file even though it exists

Tags: php

I'm running PHP 7.4.9 on Ubuntu 18.04 with Apache 2.

I'm getting this error on my PHP error log:

> "PHP Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required
> 'HTMLPurifier.auto.php' (include_path='(other
> dirs):/usr/share/php:(other dirs)') in /var/www/testing.php on line 8,
> referer: http://localhost:8080/testing.php"

So I checked if the file exists in `/usr/share/php`:

```sh
# ls -lah /usr/share/php
> -rwxrwxrwx   1 www-data www-data  274 Aug 15 15:53 HTMLPurifier.auto.php
```

So it's there. The permissions are 777 because I changed them while trying to fix the problem.

I then visited a `phpinfo();` file in the browser and checked that the dir is in the include path and that `open_basedir` is empty:

```
Directive       Local Value   Master Value
include_path    (other dirs)  .:/usr/share/php
open_basedir    no value      no value
```

I then created another PHP file and wrote this to check if php can see the file:

```php
<?php

clearstatcache();

$dir = '/usr/share/php/';
$filename = 'HTMLPurifier.auto.php';
$fullpath = $dir . $filename;

var_dump($dir);
var_dump($filename);
var_dump($fullpath);

var_dump(is_dir($dir));

$all_files = scandir($dir);

var_dump($all_files);
var_dump(file_exists($fullpath));
var_dump(file_exists($dir . $all_files[12]));
```

When I visit it in the browser I get:

```
string(15) "/usr/share/php/" // $dir

string(21) "HTMLPurifier.auto.php" // $filename

string(36) "/usr/share/php/HTMLPurifier.auto.php" // $fullpath

bool(true) // is_dir($dir)

// $all_files
array(40) {
  (other files)
  [12]=> string(21) "HTMLPurifier.auto.php"
}

bool(false) // file_exists($fullpath)

bool(false) // file_exists($dir . $all_files[12])
```

So PHP can scan the directory, can see the file there, but says it (or any other file in the dir) doesn't exists. I tested passing a file inside `/var/www` to `file_exists` and it worked. I also tried renaming the file, but got nothing.

What gives?

---

Edit: Running the above script with `strace php test.php` (as suggested by @Progman) gives me:

```
access("/usr/share/php/HTMLPurifier.auto.php", F_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(1, "bool(false)\n", 12bool(false)
)           = 12

access("/usr/share/php/HTMLPurifier.auto.php", F_OK) = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
write(1, "bool(false)\n", 12bool(false)
)           = 12
```

So it's a permission issue. Running the script as root works.

```sh
$ ls -lah /user/share
drw-rw-rw-  20 root root 4.0K Aug 16 11:52 php
```

So I tried `sudo chmod 777 /usr/share/php` and the script works. Anything less (e.g. 776) and I get permission denied. Any idea how I should set these permissions?

Comment: Are you running SELinux? If yes: Run `ls -Z /usr/share/php/` and see how it looks; should be `httpd_sys_content_t` I believe. SELinux will block access without regard to permissions if the context is disallowed for Apache default access.

Comment: Can you read the file when calling a test php script via the command line command "php"? When you get the same error message, can you run `strace php script.php` and add the output to your question?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones It’s `require_once “HTMLPurifier.auto.php”;`, the files are not in the same dir, but the required file is in the include path, so this should work.

Comment: @Markus AO, no I’m using Ubuntu 18.04 as stated in the question.

Comment: @Progman huh, running the file I wrote as a test with the PHP CLI as root works, running as a regular user doesn't. I guess it's some kind of permission issue then.

Comment: @FelipeZavan Please add the output of `strace php script.php` when run as a regular user to your question.

Comment: Have you tried changing ownership to `www-data:root` ?

Comment: Try `chmod 0755 HTMLPurifier.auto.php` and then `chown www-data:root HTMLPurifier.auto.php`. Does it work this way?

Comment: @FelipeZavan Why does the directory `/usr/share/php/` not have the `--x` permission set (which is "search" for directories)? Usually it is something like `755`, but in your chmod code it is like `666`.

Comment: @MihailMinkov Yeah, just saw that and deleted my comment :) It sounds like the web server user (`nobody`?) needs permission to access `/usr/share/php`.

Comment: Have you considered adding the file in your `/var` folder?

Comment: `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/php` and `sudo chmod 755 /usr/share/php/HTMLPurifier.auto.php` worked!  Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In linux a regular user like your normal working user or the webserver assigned user needs the directory permission "search", which is `--x` or the bit mask `1`, to access the files inside the directory. The permission `-r-` or the bit mask `2` will give you only the ability to read the file names inside a directory.

To solve the problem you have to change the chmod of the directory `/usr/share/php` to `755`.